# How to create a stacked bar chart for my problem?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have DataFrame `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Event_type","Delay_class"], 
                  data=[["A1",0],
                        ["A1",0],
                        ["A2",1],
                        ["A3",1],
                        ["A1",1],
                        ["A2",0]])
```

I want to create a stacked bar chart, in which X axis is `Event_type` and each bar is composed of the counts of values per `Delay_class`.

In my example I have 2 values of `Delay_class`. It means that each bar should be stacked of two sub-bars. The size of each sub-bar corresponds to the counts of delay class.

For example, for the event `A1` (X axis), the value of Y axis would be 2 for `Delay_class` 0, and 1 for `Delay_class` 1. The total value of Y for `A1` will be 3.

How can I get such stacked bar chart?

This is what I tried:

```
df.set_index('Event_type').T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `crosstab` + `plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)`

```
pd.crosstab(df.Event_type,df.Delay_class).plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting:) Thanks. In case of a huge number of stacked bars, is there any each way to show only first 10 bars that have largest Y values?

Comment: @ScalaBoy ummm I think it is hard to do that , since you need all the class list their , and top 10 is for each event_type .